# Strange behavior with nodejs and Circleci api

Tags: node.js, rest, circleci

We're trying to use the nodejs `https` library to make an api request to the circleci rest api and getting what seems to be malformed JSON back. Unfortunately this only happens when we use node and not, e.g. `curl`, or postman.

Here's the node code

```
var https = require('https');

https.get("https://circleci.com/api/v1/projects?circle-token=OUR-API-KEY", function(response) {
  var body = "";
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log("TEST", body);
  });
});
```

and here is first part of the result

```
TEST ({:irc_server nil, :scopes (:write-settings :view-builds :read-settings :trigger-builds :all :status :none), :irc_keyword nil,
```

Here's what it looks like when we do the same thing with `curl`

```
$ curl https://circleci.com/api/v1/projects?circle-token=OUR-API-KEY
[ {
  "irc_server" : null,
  "ssh_keys" : [ ],
  "branches" : {
    "master" : {
      "last_non_success" : {
        "outcome" : "failed",
        "status" : "failed",
        "build_num" : 41,
...
```

What we also noticed is that there seems to be some `java` residue in the `node` response. Here's a sample of a different part of the node response

```
...
"pushed_at" #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x2753b900 "2015-11-29T14:22:42.000Z"],
"added_at" #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x686553cb "2015-11-30T16:07:28.250Z"]},
...
```

As far as we can tell, this isn't a node problem because when we change the address in the script to "https://randomuser.me/api/" we get

```
TEST {"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"mrs","first":"milja","last":"makinen"},"location":{"street":"7070 pispalan valtatie","city":"geta","state":"central finland","postcode":24464},"email":"milja.makinen@example.com","login":{"username":"brownwolf135","password":"triton","salt":"Ahx7UsGp","md5":"aa3abe69ad2001470c00de947d112270","sha1":"cc0db5a4ecd489d6f53876ae143cdab117edbba3","sha256":"488268929cd6da0e50fbb61666ddd03136a3ad16914822a650c5d134db9364af"},"registered":1031987491,"dob":908944207,"phone":"05-992-273","cell":"046-791-11-07","id":{"name":"HETU","value":"60770785-G"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/73.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/73.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/73.jpg"},"nat":"FI"}],"info":{"seed":"ea5f8a5a02e09d48","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.0"}}
```

As you can see, not parentheses. Are we really the first to discover this, or are we missing something completely obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to provide the Accept-Header ( https://circleci.com/docs/api/#accept-header)?

> If you specify no accept header, we’ll return human-readable JSON with  comments. If you prefer to receive compact JSON with no whitespace or  comments, add the "application/json" Accept header